# include foreign libs in clojurescript project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, clojurescript, reagent, react-dnd

I am trying to use [react-beautiful-dnd](https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd) in my new ClojureScript and [Reagent](https://reagent-project.github.io/) application. As per the blog [here](http://lukevanderhart.com/2011/09/30/using-javascript-and-clojurescript.html), it says that I need to include the file using `:foreign-libs` in my `project.clj` file.

I have configured it as below

```
  :cljsbuild
  {:builds {:min
            {:source-paths ["src/cljs" "src/cljc" "env/prod/cljs"]
             :compiler
             {:output-to        "target/cljsbuild/public/js/app.js"
              :output-dir       "target/cljsbuild/public/js"
              :source-map       "target/cljsbuild/public/js/app.js.map"
              :optimizations :advanced
              :foreign-libs [{:file "src/cljs/react-beautiful-dnd/react-beautiful-dnd.js"}]
              :pretty-print  false}}
            :app
            {:source-paths ["src/cljs" "src/cljc" "env/dev/cljs"]
             :figwheel {:on-jsload "toka.core/mount-root"}
             :compiler
             {:main "toka.dev"
              :asset-path "/js/out"
              :output-to "target/cljsbuild/public/js/app.js"
              :output-dir "target/cljsbuild/public/js/out"
              :source-map true
              :optimizations :none
              :pretty-print  true}}



            }
   }
```

I got the compiled file from [here](https://d33wubrfki0l68.cloudfront.net/js/d5f287a23d57e9d42e6e810729077cb5c92ae85c/static/preview.ad7782b059bd6c21ece8.bundle.js) which I have copied in my project. Though after all these changes I am still not able to use `DragDropContext` or `Droppable` in my component.

In my component I have declared them as below

```
(def DragDropContext (reagent/adapt-react-class js/DragDropContext))
(def Droppable (reagent/adapt-react-class js/Droppable))
```

Can anyone please help me understand what I am doing wrong here? I am getting error as below

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: DragDropContext is not defined
    at core.cljs?rel=1508832729388:11
(anonymous) @ core.cljs?rel=1508832729388:11
```

Note: I haven't added any `provide` attribute in `foreign-libs` as I am not sure of package. Also I am not sure if I need to do some `:require` in my `core.cljs` component file.

Comment: I found an alternative to `react-beautiful-dnd`. It is listed in http://cljsjs.github.io/ as `[cljsjs/dragula "3.6.8-1"]`. Works in pretty similar way.

Answer (score 2):

I was struggeling with the same problem and found the solution. The components were put in a separate namespace and thus have to be referenced like this:

```
(def DragDropContext (reagent/adapt-react-class js/ReactBeautifulDnd.DragDropContext))
(def Droppable (reagent/adapt-react-class js/ReactBeautifulDnd.Draggable))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `:provides` (you can choose whatever ns name you'd like, e.g. `react-beautiful-dnd`) and then `require` it so it is loaded. As it depends on React, you should specify it in `requires` (e.g. `cljsjs.react` if you included React as CLJSJS dependency):

```
[{:file "src/cljs/react-beautiful-dnd/react-beautiful-dnd.js"
  :provides ["react-beautiful-dnd"]
  :requires ["cljsjs.react"]}]
```

And in your namespace:

```
(ns my.ns
  (:require
    [cljsjs.react]
    [react-beautiful-dnd]))
```

Comment: I tried this by adding a random package name (and even the one you mentioned) but it I still get the same error.

Comment: Could you please check if `react-beautiful-dnd.js` file contains the global vars that you try to reference (e.g. `js/DragDropContext`)?

Comment: yes it has `DragDropContext` but you it also has lot of other stuff which I am not sure is correct. I copied the file from https://d33wubrfki0l68.cloudfront.net/js/d5f287a23d57e9d42e6e810729077cb5c92ae85c/static/preview.ad7782b059bd6c21ece8.bundle.js